# Limit data based on UniqueCount

Tags: database, spotfire

I have charts on a tab, that should only show if 1 value from a column filter is selected.

For example if a field named: BUSINESS_UNIT has values of "HR","FIN","IT"  The charts should only show data if 1 value is filtered on. Such as "HR."
These charts do not contain the BUSINESS_UNIT field itself.

I tried using the Limit Data Using expression, but for some reason the limit expression UniqueCount(BUSINESS_UNIT)=1 doesn't work.

How would I hide the data in the charts, unless 1 BUSINESS_UNIT is selected?

Comment: for clarification. You want to start with an empty chart, but only show data if one business unit is selected. And I'm assuming that business unit is included in the same data table as the rest of the data.

Comment: Yep, start w/ blank chart. Business unit is included in the data table but not the chart.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is hide the filters panel and create radio buttons on a new text area for each property to mark data. If you need help setting this up let me know. Then in your visualisations limit data using markings and show an empty visualisation if no items are marked.
[image]

One downside to this is maintenance, if the values change you will have to update the UI.

Another possible solution (untested) is to change the filter panel properties from checkboxes to radio buttons. 
Filter Panel Properties:
http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/filter/filter_panel_properties.htm

You want it to look something like this:
http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/filter/filter_radio_buttons.htm

Comment: Thanks for this. I had a property dropdown solution in place, however, i can't manually update the UI w/ new property values. I can't do a radio button filter because, that will filter out the rest of the data on the other tabs. I really need to filter out just the chart on this one tab. Is that possible?

Comment: Try separating the charts out with a different marking, so the stuff on the other pages isn't marked.

Comment: That chart has to adhere to the other markings though from the other tabs. It basically only needs to show if 1 BUSINESS_UNIT is selected, otherwise function normally. Can a filter be applied to only a specific chart in Spotfire?